# How to launch a windows web service only when an HTTP request is made to its port?

Tags: c#, http, sockets, proxy

I am running TeamCity on my Windows server. It is a Java-based build service running TomCat and uses a hefty 300MB. I only use it occasionally so it doesn't really merit running all the time, using up memory when other services (websites) could make use of it.

Currently I have a simple protected webpage to start and stop the service when I need to use it.

I have also implemented a script to see when the service hasn't done any builds for a while and shuts the service down automatically.

So when the service is down, going to the TeamCity port (9090) results in no response. I would prefer to be able to visit the port, then something automatically fires up the service and then I can access it again.

Is it possible to have a 'middle man' application/proxy/packet sniffer to listen on port 9090, and if the service is not running, start the service and forward all requests to that service?

I would prefer to implement this as an http packet sniffer to avoid any performance issues proxying all the requests from A to B.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great, I plan to implement something in C# if I need to.

Comment: If the server doesn't do anything it will be swapped out to the page file and therefore the RAM it consumes will be again free for other programs. If you use it it will be automatically swapped in. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I think you've missed the point of TeamCity...

Comment: Peter, I haven't missed the point of TeamCity, I wanted a one click build engine to run occasionally but don't have the resources to run it 24/7. I was interested to see if this solution was possible, if there was something clever I could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I would mention how I solved this problem in the end.

I created a subdomain which runs some code to check if the TeamCity service is running. If it hasn't started then it starts the service and then redirects to the TeamCity site port. If it has already started it simply redirects. When no builds have been started for a period of time, then the service shuts down automatically, freeing memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think your own idea is pretty close to a good-enough solution: have a 'middle man' application listen on port 9090 whenever you shut the service down, and on incoming activity it should start the service and exit, freeing 9090 for the TeamCity...